# У меня есть код по использованию потокивих операций как его сделать с использованием файловых указателей?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{;
    vector<double> pos, neg;
    int zeros = 0;
    double x;


    for (ifstream in("text1.txt"); in >> x; )
    {
        if (x > 0) pos.push_back(x);
        else if (x < 0) neg.push_back(x);
        else zeros++;
    }

    ofstream out("text_copy.txt");
    for (double x : pos) out << x << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < zeros; ++i) out << 0.0 << "\n";
    for (double x : neg) out << x << "\n";
}
```

Comment: что такое "файловые указатели"?

Comment: файловые дескрипторы `int`: `open`,`close`,`read`,`write`.  файловые указатели `FILE` : `fopen`,`fclose`,`fread`,`fwrite`. Читаем доку и юзаем.

Comment: в вашем коде нет закрытия потоков. В файл ничего не запишется.

Comment: @AlexGlebe у потоков вызывается деструктор так что все закроется и запишется, а `FILE` - это потоки из С библиотеки

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> pos, neg;
    int zeros = 0;
    double x;

    FILE * in = fopen("text1.txt","r");

    for (; fscanf(in,"%lf",&x)==1; )
    {
        if (x > 0) pos.push_back(x);
        else if (x < 0) neg.push_back(x);
        else zeros++;
    }
    fclose(in);

    FILE * out = fopen("text_copy.txt","wt");

    for (double x : pos) fprintf(out,"%lf\n",x);
    for (int i = 0; i < zeros; ++i) fprintf(out,"%lf\n",0.0);
    for (double x : neg) fprintf(out,"%lf\n",x);
    fclose(out);
}
```

Так как-то...

Comment: Выдает ошибку 'fopen_s':function does not take 2 argumant

Comment: Исправил опцию открытия файла "Wt" на 'wt". НЕ знаю, как в винде, а в люнихе большая буква W приводила к *segmentation fault*.

Comment: Не знаю как в винде. Вам предложили вариант со стандартными функциями `fopen`. `fopen_s` - это не стандарт. @userofthing